# Read frames from a HTTP webcam using opencv videocapture in Kotlin

Tags: android, opencv, kotlin

I am trying to read a stream from a IP camera in Kotlin using OpenCV.
I have downloaded OpenCV 4.3.0 library for Android from here https://opencv.org/releases/ and imported it to a project in Android studio.

My question is how to achieve something equivalent to this

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://<user>:<pass>@<addr>:<port>/videostream.cgi?.mjpg')
```

and get frames from the video stream using Kotlin programming language?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What do you mean by saying " *something equivalent to this* "

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply! How can i open a video stream using OpenCV's VideoCapture and read frames using Kotlin ?